# how to display object in table in angular 7

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular7

[image]

I want to display this price and quantity **market_buy_depth_arr** from every object.
similarly from m**arket_histry_array** and **market_sel_depth_arr** to different table 
component.ts

```
 getAll(){
    this.listArray = [];
    this.dashboardService.getall().subscribe((res:any) =>{
      console.log("dashboard api res",JSON.parse(res.body))
      this.listArray = JSON.parse(res.body);
      console.log("Array fetched",this.listArray);
    }, err=>{
      console.log("Error occured in fetching all items")
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample JSON so that we can help you, a screenshot will not help a lot here. You can use `ngFor` for iterating HTML on Object from JS. [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: "HTTP Response": "200"
​
Message: {…}
​​
currncy: "TRX"
​​
is_bnb_balance: "YES"
​​
market_buy_depth_arr: (20) […]
​​​
0: {…}
​​​​
_id: Object { price: 0.00000428 }
​​​​
coin: "TRXBTC"
​​​​
created_date: "2019-06-03 11:04:02 AM"
​​​​
price: 0.00000428
​​​​
quantity: 2360893
​​​​
type: "ask"
​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
1: Object { price: 0.00000429, quantity: 713994, type: "ask", … }
​​​0: Object { price: 0.00000438, quantity: 70302, type: "ask", … }
​​​
11: Object { price: 0.00000439, quantity: 841231, type: "ask", … }
​​​

Comment: stringify your JSON array & update your question with that would be better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
buyDept : any ;
history : any ;
selDept : any ;
this.buyDept = this.listArray.market_buy_depth_arr ;
this.history = this.listArray.market_histry_array;
this.selDept = this.listArray.market_sel_depth_arr;
```

And you want to pass them to another component then you can use localstorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('BuyDeptDate', JSON.stringify(item.buyDept));
```

(Same for all)

And then in the component where you want this data, you can use :

```
buyDept : any;
this.buyDept= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('BuyDeptDate'));
```

And when you will get the data in this.buyDept you can decide which columns you want to show with this data.

I am also noob in Angular, but hope that this may help you.

Comment: unable to store in arrays  by doing above

Comment: Property 'market_buy_depth_arr' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Comment: Try this : - 


this.buyDept = this.listArray.Message.market_buy_depth_arr ;
this.history = this.listArray.Message.market_histry_array;
this.selDept = this.listArray.Message.market_sel_depth_arr;

Comment: Sorry then, there might be some changes in this it depends on JSON. If possible for you give the stringified JSON and then we can look further.